# World of Warcraft Lua - sort table

Tags: lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

I'm trying to sort a table for a addon/weakaura but I do not see how to do it ( sort by the attribut value).

Example :

```
        player = {
            value = 34
            class = Warrior,
            id    = 1
        },  
        {
            value = 1,
            class = mage,
            id    = 2
        },
        {
            value = 3443,
            class = Paladin,,
            class = 3
        }
```

I want :

```
          player = {
            value = 1,
            class = mage,
            id    = 2
        },
        {
            value = 34
            class = Warrior,
            id    = 1
        },  
        {
            value = 3443,
            class = Paladin,
            class = 3
        }
```

Someone an idea how to do this ?

Comment: The code is invalid, show the real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you fix your table declaration, you can sort the table using a custom function:

```
local player = {
  { value = 34, class = "Warrior", id = 1 },
  { value = 1, class = "mage",  id = 2 },
  { value = 3443, class = "Paladin", id = 3 },
}

table.sort(player, function(a,b) return a.value < b.value end)
```

This will sort elements of the `player` table by the value of the `value` field. You can come up with a more elaborate sorting condition if needed.

Refer to http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.sort for more information on table.sort